# QT Overwrite .txt File

Tags: qt

Im trying to overvwrite a .txt file with the part of the following code.
The overwriting process should only be triggert if the button of the messagebox getting hit.
But everytime the text got cleared without any letter.

The confusing is, if the code where the writing process is implemented like in the bottom (currently commented) isn't commented the writing process works. However I think not triggered by the button.

Hope you can help :/

```
// edit .txt File
void AnnexinV::on_SaveAsTxtButton_clicked()

{
    QMessageBox msgBoxTest(this);
    msgBoxTest.setWindowTitle("Test!");

QMessageBox msgBox(this);
msgBox.setWindowTitle("Existing File!");
msgBox.setText("The file already exists. How would you like to proceed?");
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
QPushButton *pButton1 = msgBox.addButton(tr("Overwrite"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
QPushButton *pButton2 = msgBox.addButton(tr("Add"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
QPushButton *pButton3 = msgBox.addButton(tr("Cancel"), QMessageBox::NoRole);

QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));

if (fileName != "")
{
    QFile file(QFileInfo(fileName).absoluteFilePath());

    // Change data
    if (file.exists())
    {
        msgBox.exec();

        if(msgBox.clickedButton() == pButton1)
        {

                if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
                    {
                        msgBoxTest.exec();
                        QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
                        QString CurrentTime = local.toString();
                        QString TextInput = ui->line_input->toPlainText();
                        QString TextOutput = ui->line_output->toPlainText();
                        QTextStream out(&file);
                        out << CurrentTime << ('\n');
                        out << "StringInput: " << TextInput << ('\n') ;
                        out << "StringOutput: " << TextOutput;

                    }
                    file.close();
        }


            if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Failed to save file"));
                return; // Aborted
            }
        }

//        QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
//        QString CurrentTime = local.toString();
//        QString TextInput = ui->line_input->toPlainText();
//        QString TextOutput = ui->line_output->toPlainText();
//        QTextStream out(&file);
//        out << CurrentTime << ('\n');
//        out << "StringInput: " << TextInput << ('\n') ;
//        out << "StringOutput: " << TextOutput;
//        file.close();
    }

}
```

One last question, why would this code woun't work and still leave an empty file?

```
if(msgBox.clickedButton() == pButton1)
        {

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)
                        {
                            msgBoxTest.exec();
                            QDateTime local(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
                            QString CurrentTime = local.toString();
                            QString TextInput = ui->line_input->toPlainText();
                            QString TextOutput = ui->line_output->toPlainText();
                            QTextStream out(&file);
                            out << CurrentTime << ('\n');
                            out << "StringInput: " << TextInput << ('\n') ;
                            out << "StringOutput: " << TextOutput;
    
                        }
        }
```

Comment: The commented code is being executed even when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Ty for your answer, but even if delete the comment same problem happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming when you click `pButton2` you want to append to the file, this is the solution:

```cpp
void AnnexinV::on_SaveAsTxtButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Existing file!");
    msgBox.setText("The file already exists. How would you like to proceed?");
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);

    QPushButton *pButton1 = msgBox.addButton("Overwrite", QMessageBox::YesRole);
    QPushButton *pButton2 = msgBox.addButton("Add", QMessageBox::YesRole);
    msgBox.addButton("Cancel", QMessageBox::NoRole);

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save text file", path, "Text files (*.txt)");

    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        QFile file(QFileInfo(fileName).absoluteFilePath());

        if (file.exists()) {
            msgBox.exec();

            QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag> flags = QIODevice::WriteOnly;

            if (msgBox.clickedButton() == pButton1) {
                flags |= QIODevice::Truncate;
            } else if (msgBox.clickedButton() == pButton2) {
                flags |= QIODevice::Append;
            } else {
                return;  // Cancel
            }

            if (!file.open(flags)) {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Failed to open the file!");
                return;
            }
            
            const QString currentTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
            const QString textInput = ui->line_input->toPlainText();
            const QString textOutput = ui->line_output->toPlainText();

            QTextStream out(&file);
            out << currentTime << "\nString input: " << textInput << "\nString output: " << textOutput << "\n";
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```